# Keyboard shortcuts on non-QWERTY keyboard layouts

Tags: physical, localization, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been using the Dvorak keyboard layout for a few years, and something that's always bothered me is keyboard shortcuts. On a QWERTY keyboard copy and paste are conveniently positioned as Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V, but on Dvorak they are pretty inconvenient (equivalent to Ctrl+I and Ctrl+. on QWERTY).

I would have figured the 'right' thing to do would be to have the keyboard shortcuts based on position, rather than value. So switching to Dvorak would change copy and paste to Ctrl+J and Ctrl+K (which are in the same position as C and V on QWERTY), but very few applications do this. In fact, the only one that comes to mind is Inkscape. I get that implementing it that way is harder, but not even Windows does it, so I figure there must be some further reasoning behind it?

I'm also interested in how certain international keyboards are handled, such as Arabic and Russian keyboards, which don't have any Latin characters.

Comment: Sidenote - about half the characters in Russian are the same as latin characters :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The UX answer is that **people tend to think of which key they are pressing rather than the position of the key**.  So it makes more sense to keep the shortcut linked to the key than the position of the key - even if that position is awkward.

While it could be beneficial to add profiles for different applications, you would have the situation where one program uses `Ctrl-C` and another `Ctrl-I`.  This would hurt overall UX even more.

You can **remap the system** shortcuts on many Operating Systems, which should change the shortcuts for every application.  So if someone needs them to change, this would be the best solution.

Out of interest, the Colemak layout takes common shortcut positions into account and retains most of the Qwerty shortcut positions.  It's also more efficient than Dvorak.

---

Technically and historically:

There is an intentional separation between what is pressed on a keyboard and where it is pressed.  The only thing that every OS that I have seen cares about is the keycode that the input should be - and that is as it should be.  There are many different physical keyboard designs, not to mention other devices (such as presenter pointers) which act as input devices.  This all results in it being extremely difficult to make the shortcuts based on a physical position.

Comment: Many keyboard commands are thought of more naturally in terms of what a key is rather than its location, but there are some notable major exceptions.  Historally, many DOS-based text editors assigned the meanings of control plus any of "wer asdf zxc" based upon their locations on the keyboard; the "vi" usage of "hjkl" also probably derives from their consecutive placement.  Back before Win7 killed my favorite text editor, I would have liked to try a layout which used Dvorak for non-control keys but qwerty for control keys, but the way keyboard mapping is handled wouldn't support that.

Comment: "It's also more efficient than Dvorak." <citation needed>  [It is really up to debate which is better](http://xahlee.info/kbd/dvorak_vs_colemak.html)  If you type in other languages besides English, Dvorak(or a programmer) is debatable better do to hand alternating and symbol placement(which dvorak did much much better IMO).

Comment: @William I should have added a qualification there.  Colemak is more efficient than Dvorak in the task that both of them were specifically designed for.  That is typical English prose.  Of course there are specialist areas or languages where they aren't as good.  For example, I type a lot of Dutch, and some of the more common letters in Dutch are rarely used in English, so for that task Colemak isn't ideal.  It's still better than QWERTY by a mile though, just not as optimal as when typing English prose.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what would be most appropriate for a Dvorak keyboard.  If one would want to keep the mapping of C to Copy, then G and R could work for Cut and Paste.

I don't believe that there is any particular UX reason for having the cut, copy and past exactly at the X, C an V position.  In fact, even among qwerty keyboard these keyboard combinations would differ.  The combination of <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> on an Apple keyboard is very different from <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on a IBM PC keyboard.

[image]
[image]

<strike>From a UX point of view, shortcuts s*ck.</strike>
I was young and dumb when I wrote the statement above, but [I'm much older and much wiser now...](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/30682/95) :-)
From a UX point of view, shortcuts can be useful.  The research is not conclusive, but there's no doubt that the shortcuts must be memorized and practiced to achieve their potential.

The memorization part is two-folded.  The actual key-sequence is one aspect, the spatial position is another aspect.  Our spatial memory is pretty strong (you might know proximately *where* things are, but you don't necessarily remember *the name* of the thing you're looking for (just like this guy has has arranged his desktop icons: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=rVC7I5VcTiw#t=479s), but I can't claim that position is more important than the key-name.

I would claim, however, that *grouping the shortcuts* would make it easier to memorize them.  (And perhaps easier to use them).

> Thus, the appropriate solution would be either CTRL + |F|G|C|R| (where
>   C=Copy), or CTRL + |:|Q|J|K| if the "spatial memories" from a
>   qwerty-layout is still there.  It could also be advocated that the
>   ergonomics would be better at the |:|Q|J|K| position.

Comment: From a UX point of view shortcuts suck? Where do you get that from? The fact that they are not *intuitive* doesn't mean that they are not *useful*. Shortcuts are one of the more useful tools in the arsenal when designing systems optimized for speed and efficiency rather than intuitiveness.

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky: +1, I couldn't live without short cuts...

Comment: I guess my POV got heavy influenced by Bruce "Tog" Tognazzini a looong time ago :-). _"Since users do experience the illusion that keyboarding is faster [...] Even when using "shortcuts" will actually slow them down."_ From one of [his letters](http://www.asktog.com/TOI/toi06KeyboardVMouse1.html). I know this is heavily debated, but I honestly can't remember that I have seen any study that proves that shortcuts actually *do* improve speed and efficiency. Only subjective opinions...

Comment: @Marjan: Me neither! :-)  But still, I honestly believe that todays shortcut regime is a mess.  I have four different shortcuts for the "Find" and "Replace" commands in four different applications (from the same vendor!).  Using CTRL+B in Notepad gives me the "Find dialog", but in Wordpad it will makes my text **bold**.  To search in Wordpad I need to use CTRL+F - which would make my text **bold** in *MS Word*.

Comment: Well, the obvious use case is heavy data entry. I think even Bruce would agree that when the user is typing, it's better to let him achieve things without taking his hands off the keyboard than making him reach for the mouse and back.

Comment: @Vitaly: Well, that's the thing. He *never* agreed: http://www.asktog.com/SunWorldColumns/S02KeyboardVMouse3.html  When you say "move your hand *all the way* to to the mouse" he replies with ["stop all cognitive processing on the primary task, enter a 2.5 second decision-making process"](http://www.asktog.com/TOI/toi22KeyboardVMouse2.html).   And the annoying thing is that he's got a $50 million R&D study to back him up...

Comment: @JørnE.Angeltveit Can you provide a link to where that study is published? When it was published how the study was conducted etc. etc. ?

Comment: @Pieter: Do you mean the $50 million R&D study? I don't believe you will be able to "read up" on that study from a single link. ;-) The reference to the study is in [the first link](http://www.asktog.com/TOI/toi06KeyboardVMouse1.html).  No link provided here, though, but the initial WIMP work Apple (and Xerox) did in the early days are pretty well known...  Perhaps there are some references in [his book](http://www.amazon.com/Tog-Interface-Bruce-Tognazzini/dp/0201608421)?

Comment: @JørnE.Angeltveit No, you won't get me there ;) [However, as Tog himself notes, when the keyboard shortcut is already memorized and well understood, it's a clear productivity win](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/revisiting-keyboard-vs-the-mouse-pt-1.html).

Comment: @Vitaly: Get you where?  I'm not trying to get you anywhere...  Just let me clarify:  I'm *not* and anti shortcut guy, and this is not any crusade against keyboard shortcuts.  I find them useful and I would definitely miss them if they were gone.  But: I *cannot* claim that I'm *actually* more productive the times I use shortcuts compared to the the times I use the mouse.  What I have experienced is that the mental workload is much heavier when doing shortcuts (try to count backwards from 100 while you're doing a task).  Serious research *can* conclude with something illogical...

Comment: In that sense it's all about muscle memory, when you need to copy something, does your mind go like ohw I need to press ctrl+c or do your fingers already do the action before you start thinking about how to do it? Actually in some sense you could argue that any use of a key is using a shortcut, and you can't tell me that clicking a virutal keyboard is faster then blind typing.

Comment: @Pieter: No. Plain typing is not equal to shortcuts.  Obviously, *some* shortcuts are remembered very well and are executed with less memory processing.  CTRL+C is probably the easiest and the most consistent one.  Opening the "Find dialog" (which is a common task too) has different shortcuts in different tools.  In those cases (and for shortcuts you don't use that often), it could have been faster to "just hit the toolbar" than to "figure out" the shortcut.  But I'm not trying to advocate WIMP, here!  I'm just pointing out what the research says, and that this should be taken into account.

Comment: @JørnE.Angeltveit Nevermind, I was joking :). I disagree with this reasoning but this is not the place for it, so some other time :).

Comment: @Vitaly :-) Oh, no hard feelings.  I was just a bit unsure if I had offended you somehow.  Pure text and a few smiles can come to short sometimes.  (I'm not sure if I agree with myself or the research here, me neither ;-)

Comment: @Vitaly, I've given my answer a second thought, and I rest my case ;-)  The statement was silly and misleading, and it was not relevant for the question.  [The answer is updated...](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/30671/95)

Comment: @JørnE.Angeltveit Way to go for the serious approach and the effort!

Answer (score 0):

Let me add an international perspective. Users across the world who don't use a QWERTY keyborad are already used to using keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> for undo according to the position of those keys on their keyboard. For example, take this AZERTY keyborad layout, generally used by French speakers:

[image: Photo of AZERTY keyboard]

To launch the undo action, the user would press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, with the Z being in the top row, not the bottom row as it would be in a QWERTY keyboard. This applies even to keyboard shortcuts which are placed in convenient locations in a QWERTY keyboard, like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> for cut, copy and paste, or <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>L</kbd> for left, down, up, and right respectively in Vim. We're just used to it.

What about keyboard layouts that don't have letters like X, C and V, such as an Arabic keyboard layout? How would you launch the keyboard shortcut for undo <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>?

[image: Photo of Arabic keyboard]

Generally, the user does not need to manually switch to a QWERTY, AZERTY or other Latin keyboard layout in order to use keyboard shortcuts that use a modifier like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd>. Once you hold down the modifier like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, you can press the <kbd>Z</kbd> as it would be found in a Latin keyboard layout. I've noticed this difference in operating systems, though:

- On Windows, with an Arabic keyboard layout enabled, once you hold down a modifier like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, you need to press the subsequent letter key (like <kbd>Z</kbd>) where it would be found on a QWERTY keyboard, even if no QWERTY keyboard layout is configured. (This is annoying if you are switching between Dvorak and Arabic, as the keyboard shortcuts change)
- On Linux, with an Arabic keyboard layout enabled, once you hold down a modifier like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, you need to press the subsequent letter key (like <kbd>Z</kbd>) where it would be found in the alternative keyboard layout. So if your alternative keyboard layout is Dvorak, it switches to that, if it is QWERTY, it switches to QWERTY.

Answer (score 0):

The important point is consistency. When you're using Dvorak, you're probably being used to the position of ctrl-x, ctrl-c, ctrl-v, even when they are not that convenient. When now *one* application tries to make it easier, it actually makes you think as it behaves different from the other applications.

As others said, operation systems allow to remap some keys. Try to use the OS APIs as much as possible, so users can configure the keys themselves and your program just does what the toolkit does on the standard shortcut without knowing about the user's keyboard layout.