# Are there any recent studies of the "Keyboard vs Mouse"-issue?

Tags: research, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

Back in the late 80's, Apple Human Interface concluded that the mouse is faster than the keyboard, objectively.  But also that every test person *subjectively thought* that the keyboard was faster.

Quote from the book ["Tog on Interface"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201608421), by [Bruce Tognazzini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Tognazzini) (originaly [published as an article](http://www.asktog.com/TOI/toi06KeyboardVMouse1.html) at [asktog.com](http://asktog.com)):

> We've done a cool $50 million of R & D on the Apple Human Interface.
>   We discovered, among other things, two pertinent facts:
>
> - Test subjects consistently report that keyboarding is faster than mousing.
> - The stopwatch consistently proves mousing is faster than keyboarding.

This has caused many arguments and discussions (eg: [by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/revisiting-keyboard-vs-the-mouse-pt-1.html) and [at skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4355/is-using-a-mouse-less-efficient), but all of these are based on subjective assumptions.

---

So, I'm looking for some other, newer studies that could either verify or refute those findings from the 80's.  **Are there any recent studies on the "Keyboard vs Mouse"-issue?**

I'm concerned about two aspects:

1. *The time aspect.*  Performance vs preference.
2. *The workload aspect.*  What's the learning curve like?  How many shortcuts does the novice user use, and how many shortcuts are the experienced user able to handle?

---

**Update:**

*I don't doubt that keyboard shortcuts are faster is many situations*, but I would like to see some more research on the issue.  Conducting one myself isn't an option (and it would be unnecessary if it's already done).  Subjective opinions and referral to "the obvious" won't give me the answers I'm searching either.

[KLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke-level_model)/[GOMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOMS)/[MHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_processor_model) are all good models that could function as a theoretical basis to explain what's happening.  Any reference to any such work on this area would be good too[...](http://memegenerator.net/instance/32082431)

*So why am I asking about this?*
Well, as a UX professional, I would like to base my stack of knowledge on research, not assumptions.  IMHO, the fundamentals of UX are based on "find out, don't assume".

It can be difficult to convince people about the UX-work.  Having proper research is one of the most important tools we have.  (Letting them observe users use their software is *the* most important one).

*But it is so obvious!...*
No it isn't.  When users are confronted with multiple design options, the correlation between preference and performance is very low.  Only *25%* would prefer the solution with the best performance.

We also know that heavy mental workload makes you *think* that you're effective, even if you're not (just like the Apple research concluded).  So the feeling "this is the fastest solution" doesn't actually *make it* the fastest solution.

*Why is it important to know this? Just provide both, and let the users choose!*
Well, if I'm going to train a user group, I would want to base my advises on *something*.  Right now, the only research I can base my advice on says "Minimize the use of shortcuts.  You'll just fool yourself and *believe* you're faster than you actually are."

*Some of the specific issues I'm looking for in the research:*

- What's our capability to remember shortcuts (number of shortcuts,  decay rate, etc). The general MHP-research actually says *something* about this.
- Performance differences.  (Something can be worked out from the KLM/GOMS theories.)
- What is the performance improvement for the shortcuts you remember immediately.
- What is the performance loss (if any) in the situations where you have to "think twice" to remember a shortcut.
- What is the "recovery cost" in the situations where you use the wrong shortcut (or didn't remember it after thinking twice).
- Will the mental workload of "remembering" a shortcut affect the main work task?  Say you're doing accounting and need to handle 5-7 "chunks" of information already.
- Are there any thresholds you can use to say:  "Just use N number of keyboard shortcuts and stick to the mouse+toolbar for the other commands."
- What would the *capability/advice* be for each of these cells:
  [image]

---

I know these questions are very specific, and that's why I kept the question general in the first place.

Remember: **I'm just asking for references to any research,** I'm not asking for a winner or a conclusion, nor am I asking for specific answers to the issues I've raised in the "update" section above.  This question *is* answerable...

Comment: This is going to depend on the task you are comparing.  If you've watched an expert Vim user, there is no doubt that the keyboard is faster than the mouse for that.  For graphics programs, maybe not.

Comment: I Agree with John. This question is so context/task/personal preference sensitive that it looks impossible to generally declare one being more efficient than the other.

Comment: The mouse is always slower when I do most of the work using the keyboard. The keyboard is always slower when I do most of the work using the mouse. In other words: slowness is not function of mouse or keyboard use, but of having to switch from one to the other.

Comment: @MarjanVenema Do you use the keyboard shortcuts or the toolbar when you format your answers here at the StackExchange network?

Comment: @John: Well, any *research/study* would do ;-)

Comment: @JørnE.Angeltveit it would only apply to the narrow situation that is being studied.  Imagine having to use a mouse for text entry - painful.  Imagine drawing with a keyboard - equally painful.  Most applications lie somewhere between those two extremes.

Comment: @John: An interesting task would be to open a document (text, code or image) and then perform some everyday editing on that document (edit, manipulate, search, replace, save, undo, print, extract method, compile, debug, insert row, sort columc, add image).  It's the *execution of an action* that is interesting to compare.  Mouse & Toolbar vs Keyboard & Shortcut.

Comment: @JørnE.Angeltveit: Both. Haven't learned them all yet :) In GMail and GoogleReader I use the short cuts extensively. Yes, it takes some time to remember them, but once you do, they can't be beaten...

Comment: Surely keyboard + mouse still takes the cake though?

Comment: As a Wacom Tablet user, I'm much more interested in a keyboard vs. touchpad vs. mouse vs. pen tablet interface study! I feel faster on my wacom, and I'm sure with people migrating to laptops, asking about touchpads vs. keyboards seems like less of a contest...

Comment: @John: Regarding your first comment: How many commands would you say that the expert Vim user could remember?  10,50,100?  Does the rarely used shortcuts affect the mental focus of the main task?

Comment: @AndroidH: Regarding your first comment:  It *is* possible to answer this question, because I'm looking for *any* research/study/paper on the topic.  I'm not looking for a winner.

Comment: @Marjan: Regarding your fist comment:  Have you actually measured the performance difference, or are you just assuming?  (I'm honestly just curious, not trying to "get you" ;-) ... And I don't doubt *at all* that the keyboard is faster.  I use CTRL+SHIFT+I,  CTRL+SHIFT+U,  CTRL+SHIFT+R,  CTRL+SHIFT+P, CTRL+SHIFT+C, F7, F8, F9, F12 etc *every* day ;-).  The interesting part is where the limit goes and where the keyboard performance curve and mouse/toolbar performance curve crosses).

Comment: @Rachel: You could ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @JørnE.Angeltveit Vim is different in that the command system is more like a language with verbs, nouns, and adjectives.  So the command set is not too big, but the possible effective command set is huge.  In general, people will remember what they use a lot, whether it's 10 or 100 commands.

Comment: @GB: Are you sure about that?  Say you want to remember 100 shortcuts, how often is "often"?

Comment: @JørnE.Angeltveit You are not going to find academic research to generically answer your question because there are too many variables to control experimentally. This is why KLM/GOMS exist. They are not theoretical models. If you give me an interface that supports both the keyboard and the mouse, using KLM I can tell you with a higher degree of statistical certainty which method is faster. However, that information will be of no value to anyone else unless dealing with an identical interface.

Comment: @superduperfly: KLM/GOMS are still theoretical *models* trying to represent the real world. (Really good ones, though!).  They are based on several empirical observations and experiments, and the work Card et al. have done to establish this model is really impressive.  No-one is born with a physical "visual processor" in their brain. This is just an analogy they have used to visualize their research.  The cognitive processor cycle time they use (70ms) is just the mean value of their data.  They use terms like fast-man and slow-man (25-170ms) to emphasize the variation in the human brain...

Comment: @superduperfly: Perhaps KLM/GOMS/MHP *is* the best research on the field.  I don't know, thats why I ask :-)  You really shouldn't have deleted your answer, because I think it was very relevant.  (Perhaps improve it to show the relaton to keyboard/mouse performance times and cognitive workload.)  BTW, have you tried to work out a GOMS model and compare it to empirical data?  I have (with NGOMSL), and I have two experiences from that work: 1) It's really timeconsuming (and fragile) 2) The models are impressively accurate :-)

Comment: @JørnE.Angeltveit I feel like it is after having gone down this same road as you are going down. I am not familiar with NGOMSL but your work sounds interesting. I would like to learn more. Someone else deleted my answer; I took it to mean they felt it was completely unrelated. I was ok with that since as it stood it kind of was in relation to your question.

Comment: @superduperfly.  Deleted answer: Hm... :-(    [NGOMSL (Natural GOMS Language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NGOMSL) is just a structured way of writing GOMS-statements.  Kinda like a programming language where you define *"methods"* with a *"method header"* and a *"return" statement*.  Methods can *call* other methods and you have *selection rules*...  IIRC, the [Kieras(1988)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NGOMSL#cite_note-1) article is the best read to get the basics.

Comment: Didn't measure. Rereading my comment, I am not sure whether it is clear that I did not mean doing it by mouse would be slower if you are used to doing it by keyboard, or vice versa. I meant that having to switch during execution of a task will always be slower than being able to complete a task either by keyboard, or by mouse. the physical movement necessary in itself is enough to make having to switch slower.

Comment: @superduperfly could you add your references to KLM/GOMS/MPH and emphasize their relation to this topic?

Comment: @ AndroidHustle Try telling that to a hard core VIM user.  They claim that taking their hand off the keyboard to mouse completely destroys their flow / concentration / slows them down so much as to be completely infeasible.  LOLOLOL, I just noticed people making this very claim.  "I meant that having to switch during execution of a task will always be slower than being able to complete a task either by keyboard, or by mouse. the physical movement necessary in itself is enough to make having to switch slower."

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'll put in an answer myself here...
(Hopefully this will inspire to submit more research links...)

Searching the [ACM digital library](http://dl.acm.org) and a few other resources I found a few related articles.

---

**[Categorization costs for hierarchical keyboard commands](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1978942.1979351&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE&CFID=231586142&CFTOKEN=80641087)** (2011)
*by Miller, Denkov and Omanson*

*Summary*

> Previous research comparing methods of issuing commands
>   found that **selecting a toolbar item is faster than selecting
>   an item from two menus** with either a mouse or keyboard
>   shortcut. Over the course of 90 trials, however, **the keyboard
>   method showed the most improvement**, nearing the toolbar
>   response time. The study presented in this paper compared
>   the response time of the keyboard method across 240 trials
>   when items were drawn from a single versus two menus.  Throughout the trials,** the 1-menu condition produced selection
>   times that were on average 600 ms to 800 ms faster than
>   the 2-menu condition** suggesting users in the 2-menu condition
>   were not able to bypass the menu decision by chunking
>   the 3-key sequence into one cognitive unit. [...]
>   Previous studies have shown that **practiced users can select a command
>   faster using a simple key sequence** than by using the mouse to select
>   the menu from a toolbar or menu [6, 7, 9].  In these studies, the simple keyboard command
>   typically includes a control-key followed by a single key
>   press for choosing the command. In contrast, a more recent
>   study [10] suggests that **more complex key sequences do not have such a clear advantage over toolbar selection**. [...] Perhaps with more practice,
>   users would eventually chunk the whole key sequence
>   as one unit for selecting a command.
>   [...]
>   Throughout the trials, **the 1-menu condition produced selection
>   times that were on average 600 ms to 800 ms faster than
>   the 2-menu condition**. Since both conditions required participants
>   to type the same key presses, this difference in time
>   indicates the mental cost of category selection.

---

**[Hidden Costs of Graphical User Interfaces: Failure
to Make the Transition from Menus and Icon
Toolbars to Keyboard Shortcuts](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://coursesite.uhcl.edu/HSH/PeresSc/Professional/Lane_IJHCI2005-18.pdf&ei=iZTQULnSC4ephAfRxYDoBA&usg=AFQjCNExYVMcHJ_m-7dvexiWg3jcQ92GOA&sig2=Nym0lJ4xV-5Hewn0wvkD9A&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.ZG4)** (2005)
*by Lane, Napier, Peres and Sándor*

*Summary:*

> [...] It would seem natural for users to migrate from
>   the use of easy-to-learn menu and icon methods to the more efficient method of keyboard
>   shortcuts as they gain experience. To investigate the extent to which this transition
>   takes place, 251 experienced users of Microsoft Word were given a questionnaire
>   assessing their choice of methods for the most frequently occurring commands. **Contrary
>   to our expectations, most experienced users rarely used the efficient keyboard
>   shortcuts**, favoring the use of icon toolbars instead. A second study was done to verify
>   that keyboard shortcuts are, indeed, the most efficient method. Six participants performed
>   common commands using menu selection, icon toolbars, and keyboard shortcuts.
>   **The keyboard shortcuts were, as expected, the most efficient.** We conclude that
>   even experienced users are inefficient in their use of graphical interfaces. One possible
>   way to improve user efficiency is for training programs to provide a roadmap for users
>   to make the transition from using pull-down menus and clicking icon toolbars to issuing
>   keyboard shortcuts.

---

**[Comparison of Mouse and Keyboard Efficiency](http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/sjost/csc423/examples/anova/efficiency.pdf)** (2010)
*Omanson, Miller, Young an Schwantes*

*Summary:*

> Overall, the **Toolbar-Mouse method was the fastest**, while the **Menu-Keyboard condition showed the most
>   improvement**. A GOMS-based model is presented that accounts for differences among methods. This work
>   confirms the use of toolbars for common commands, but also suggests that **for heavily-used interfaces, keyboard
>   shortcuts can be as efficient as toolbars** and have the advantage of providing fast access to all commands.

---

Comment: Thank you compiling this and actually supporting your beliefs with research. Is there anything new regarding this?

Answer (score 16):

I don't see the need for any new studies in this area.  The issue is that people usually take the results out of context.  You can't comparing using a mouse to learning a keyboard command and then using it.  Apples and oranges. Let me summarise what we know.

**If you don't know the keyboard command, it is usually faster to use the mouse** as it has a lower learning curve.

**If you *do* know the command, the keyboard is much faster than the mouse**.  But then you have to have taken the time to learn it.

In my mind the issue is not that pressing for most applications as **you should strive to allow both methods** so that people can choose the way that suits them most.  If they are going to invest time into becoming more efficient in a program they will typically use the keyboard more, but if it's something they will rarely use, then they will opt for a mouse more often than not.

Comment: It's the research behind *"If you do know the command the keyboard is much faster than the mouse"* I'm looking for.  I'm not sure if this statement is true (or rather: I would prefer to be able to back that statement up with some research).

Comment: Based on the KLM and GOMS model, John's statement (If you don't know the keyboard command, it is usually faster to use the mouse) is absolutely correct. Mentally preparing takes ~ 1.35 seconds, moving hands to keyboard from mouse takes ~ .4 seconds, pointing with a mouse (excluding click) takes ~ 1.1 seconds, etc. You can review "The Psychology of Human Computer Interaction" by Stuart Card, Thomas Moran and Allen Newell or simply search for any research related to GOMS for more information.

Comment: I cannot quote a body of research to convince you of my POV, but perhaps you can run your own test and reach your own conclusion.  Take a graphics designer in PS who deserves the rank of 'legendary' and record the time it takes and the number of keyboard shortcuts they use in a session.  Then ask them to do the same thing using only the mouse.  You shouldn't need a stopwatch to reach a conclusion.  I generally agree with the other comments here that it all depends on the actions taken and knowledge of the software.

Comment: @JørnE.Angeltveit I would see a need for new studies if they were answering a question which would be applicable and for which we did not have existing results.  It's like having a study on whether a car is faster than a person.  It depends on the environment you are testing in.

Comment: @JørnE.Angeltveit you missed the point. On a nice tarred road car wins.  On a narrow path up a mountain the person wins. The point is that each application will be different, and so the result will have to be only loosely applicable.  That is already satisfied by existing studies.

Comment: @John: OK. I missed that point, there :-)  Thank for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

As it is written it depends of the user experience and the software goal. An expert uses more keyboard more than beginners. 
A text data application (example CRM) is more used with keyboard and a bitmap drawing software is more used with mouse and a vectorial drawing software is more used with both to cut, paste, copy, paste, group, ungroup for example with keyboard, move objects slowly with arrow keyboard and select or rapidly move with mouse.

The best solution is to propose as much as possible the two ways.

Answer (score 2):

From [Tog himself](http://www.asktog.com/TOI/toi06KeyboardVMouse1.html)

> Not that any of the above True Facts will stop the religious wars. And, in fact, I find myself on the opposite side in at least one instance, namely editing. By using Command X, C, and V, the user can select with one hand and act with the other. Two-handed input. Two-handed input can result in solid productivity gains (Buxton 1986).

It ultimately depends on the scenario and function for comparison, instead of judging one against the other you need to measure the two in conjuction.  2¢

Answer (score 1):

Both mouse and keyboard have their own universal language. Mouse has it's move, hover, click, drag, drop, double-click, right-click, wheel up/down, middle-click style universal language.

Keyboard has Tab, Enter, Shift-Tab, Ctrl-Tab, Cursor keys, Shift+Cursor keys, Ctrl-C/X/V/Z/A/Y, Ctrl-W, PgUp, PgDn, Home, End etc. That is called CUA (Common User Access) standard and is quite compatible across operating systems.

Similar to how we can explore an application with mouse, we can actually explore an application using keyboard too. When I want to check out the menu I just press Alt on Windows and navigate with cursor keys. Or I hold Alt key and see what gets underlined and press that letter.

When you learn that universal language once, learning application specific functionality for keyboard may not be too different than the mouse. You actually perform the same ritual with mouse too only you're not aware of it. When you use your paint program, if the icon is unfamiliar, you hover on it to learn what it does, and when you do that in some cases you are presented with a shortcut key in parentheses too.

Despite their commonality there are two very important differences between the two:

- Keyboard navigation is more sequential hence lacks "direct pointing" and dragging abilities
- Mouse sucks at typing :)

That means they are complementary and can be more efficient than the other in certain scenarios. I think Jeff Atwood's approach about leveraging both when which is more efficient is very sane.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the conversation revolves around getting a task done quickly, but it does not address the distraction incurred and that effect on the rest of the workflow.  In the medical records realm physicians are given numerous dialog boxes to get their orders entered and notes written.  Unfortunately, having to shift from one dialog to another gets quite distracting.  We never saw such distractions when we had written orders that we could keep adding to while writing notes or looking up labs.

I don't find research evaluating whether keyboard entry versus multiple changing dialogs requiring mouse clicking is better.

The research study that looked at mouse vs toolbar vs keyboard was rather limited, didn't have multiple menu's, nor multiple complex tasks.  The cost of switching between entirely different input systems was not addressed.  The fallacy of multitasking has now been demonstrated by multiple sources.  I suspect users that think keyboard is faster are discussing their experiece in the ecosystem rather than just a limited measure of performance on one isolated trivial task.